# Can an RSS item be altered with a hook?

Tags: hooks, rss, api, regex

I would like to alter the content of each item in a site's RSS feed with a regular expression.

The [rss2_item](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/rss2_item) hook is close but it is run just after the item has been output, so is only really useful for *adding* data to a feed item, I need to *alter* the item with a regex before output.

Is there any way to do this with an `add_action` hook or do I need to create a whole new `rss.php` feed file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[the_content_feed](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content_feed) is the hook I needed. In my case I am running a regex to replace relative URLs to absolute ones, so I added the following code to `functions.php`

```
add_action('the_content_feed', 'relative_to_absolute_links');
function relative_to_absolute_links($content) {
    return preg_replace("/(src=['\"]){1}\/{1}([^\/][^'\"]+)(['\"])/im", "$1" . get_site_url() . "/$2$3", $content);
}
```